# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'key') Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got two interfaces

```
  export interface ClosureItem{
    id:string;
    name:string;
    visibility?:boolean;
  }

  export interface ClosureAllItems{
      [K:string]:ClosureItem;
      Financials:ClosureItem;
      Risk:ClosureItem;
      Issue:ClosureItem;
      AR2:ClosureItem;
  }
```

When I try to set a value to the properties, its saying

```
 Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'key')
```

Here is how my code looks

```
 myClosureItems!:ClosureAllItems;
 constructor(){}
  ....
  ....

 setitems(){
      let k:string[]=["Financials","AR2","Risk","Issue"];
      k.forEach(element=>{
           this.myClosureItems[element]={id:element,name:element,visibility:true}
      });
 }
```

*Here in second interface I have specified the K:string as to avoid index issue when calling using string names

Comment: myClosureItems!:ClosureAllItems = {};

Comment: `d.key`? What is `d`?

Comment: @MikeOne Now its saying Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ClosureAllItems': Financials,  Risk, Issue, AR2.

Comment: @R.Richards Please ignore that which is something happened when I copied it. I have updated the question..

Answer (score 0):

`myClosureItems` is undefined. You have to initialize it.

```js
    myClosureItems = {} as unknown as ClosureAllItems;
    // or
    // myClosureItems: Partial<ClosureAllItems> = {};
```

See full demo [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=54&pln=27&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBsD2BnArlCASUgFtkBvAKGRuWABMAuZbMKUAcwG5raQ4SEZq3YhuvGgDdg2YACNg6YGACeAfmZzMmdBDggeAX0qVQkWIhQYc%20CAEF06YhBLYKE5AG0A0sLacAXWZrPAJnEh5aZAAxUH0EYDh0bGCsUKJSSNoAJRkAa1SbMMyPQmw8ITQ023CsmjtsgCZC9NrKY0oEdDhy5AARF0wARncokhUQmtJsAEIW2wcnaZ4PbAgwZRdsAAoASlGo2l0wZAKWfzFPAOQAXi8AIlj%20EASk7HuAGmR7hsbP79y2Dy-3uZQq9wCdUOeQAdDBMFAAKKIAAW2wgukE4FuAD4DodDmAUTIYeNJsUtp4MS4IOBrndyHQmMhqViwF9%20IJmKzaezkNJZAolKpmGxcChjASaIZdlDjB0uj03AMSJhGvjkGTqhTXLcKIZkD1kLgQHkQJgAO4gQ1ucn2RzhbBQgD0zuQCI8rs1E21GS2zAACnAoBskgAeO2LR14hmGFZRNYbaZ7DVRY6nPyiDhXPWeR5xF6JZIg34gwHAr6g8riiFQqKw%20FI1HozG83GpqVEklaop%201xU1t0vWMhjcwd8zmVHngL4C%20SKZQqUVQcXISVSmVy9omEAQC39QaNPYwxObVx7Hhe3f7lXDY%20n5Oy5BexFQKAI4L6c0nRPIAAO75-tAGwQG4mAwMaID0BAMCgBA9DINsiYbGIyAAORPPERbYGh%20yUEAA).